# Resfresh Fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

how can I recreate a fragment by calling oncreateview method? I have a fragment that I use to insert new data through forms, after clicking on the button I would like to recreate the fragment by deleting the data entered in the EditText. I try with attach and deattach but the data is not deleted.

Comment: It is not good idea to recreate full fragment. I would suggest to setText("") to EditText-s

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are getting the right fragment by assigning a tag and retrieving it by its tag as follows

**Inserting the fragment**

```java
Fragment fragment = ...;
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, "YourTag");
transaction.commit();
```

**Refreshing the fragment**

```java
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YourTag");
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.detach(fragment);
transaction.attach(fragment);
transaction.commit(); // This line is very important
```